# Перенаправления в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Попросили настроить у сайта перенаправления на адреса с символом `/` в конце. Ставил правило в `.htaccess`, но ничего не помогает - на некоторых страницах как вводишь, так и остается, на других - перенаправляет, наоборот, на адреса без `/`. Причем, еще и в разных браузерах по-разному. На `mozilla` и `webkit` если перейти к `http://site.ru/`, то в адресной строке останется `http://site.ru`, а в `ie` символ `/` на конце остается. От чего еще это может зависеть?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.site.ru/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Правило свое покажите.

Comment: ну дак что и как вы настроили?

Comment: @LLENN, правило добавил в вопрос. Больше ничего не настраивал, потом удалил, и осталось все как было. Такое ощущение, что правило это ни на что не повлияло.

Comment: Что значит `перенаправления на адреса с символом / в конце`? Это типа ссылка вида `http://site.com/test` должна стать `http://site.com/test/` ? Покажите пример реальной ссылки (имя домена можете изменить) у которой нет слэша в конце и он не появляется после запроса.

Comment: @de_frag, вот, например? `http://site.ru` - если и ставить его в конце, то он удаляется браузером (`firefox`, `chrome`). При этом, `ie`, наоборот, добавляет, если написать без него.

Возможно, дело в тонкостях работы браузеров - что-то типа адресов, ведущих к скриптам и адресов, ведущих к папкам, так я для себя это охарактеризовал. Но, конечно, понимания внутренней логики пока нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ч.1**

Ok.

Давайте рассмотрим обращение к корню сайта `http://site.com`.

Начнем с `Chrome` и/или `Firefox`.

Набираем в адресной строке `http://site.com`, жмем `Enter` и получаем в итоге строку `site.com`. Т.е. по пути "потеряли" `http://`.

Ладно, идем дальше. Набираем `http://site.com/`, жмем `Enter` - результат тот же: `site.com`. Теперь еще и последний слэш потерялся.

Хорошо, запомнили.

Теперь идем в IE. Повторяем все тоже самое: сначала `http://site.com`, затем со слэшом `http://site.com/`. Результат в адресной строке одинаковый - `http://site.com/`.

В отличие от Chrome/Firefox мы не "потеряли" `http://`, но получили "навязчивый" последний слэш.

Запомнили.

Теперь посмотрим на все это со стороны веб-сервера (Apache).

А со стороны веб-сервера всё выглядит следующим образом: все запросы из всех браузеров (что со слэшом в конце, что без) `GET / HTTP/1.1`. В этом несложно убедиться, посмотрев логи.

Что всё это значит?

Это значит только одно: все браузеры на свое усмотрение "декорируют" адресную строку.

Chrome/Firefox прячут название протокола `http://`, а также прячут последний слэш, означающий в конкретно этом случае корень сайта. Хотя при этом формируют правильный запрос к корню сайта `GET /`.

IE не прячет ничего, а даже "подправляет" строку слэшом в конце, однозначно показывая пользователю, что он идет в корень сайта.

На мой взгляд в этом случае IE даже больше прав.

Вот, собственно, и все тонкости в этом вопросе.

Кстати, есть еще такой браузер `Microsoft Edge`. Так вот он ведет себя в этом случае аналогично Chrome/Firefox-у.

**Ч.2**

Ну и чтобы не было некой недосказанности в этом вопросе, то все, что описано выше, не имеет отношения к запросам вида `http://site.com/somepath`. Тут имеется ввиду, что символы `http://` браузеры по прежнему спрячут, но вот появится слэш в конце или нет - это уже не браузерное дело.

И чтобы коротенько - сразу простейший пример.

Имеем Apache и отправляем ему запрос `http://site.com/somepath`, и пусть `somepath` это директория в корне сайта, а в ней лежит индексный файл `index.html`. Т.е. также будет справедлив запрос `http://site.com/somepath/index.html`. Но нас интересует первый запрос без слэша.

Итак, прилетает на сервер `GET /somepath`. В этот момент Apache еще даже не знает, что это такое - директория/файл/НЛО/etc. Поэтому сначала идет обычный поиск по файловой системе относительно корня сайта (DocumentRoot). И вот выяснилось, что `somepath` это директория.

Забегая вперед скажу, что мгновением позже в браузере строка `http://site.com/somepath` превратится в `http://site.com/somepath/`. Почему?

Потому что, в тот самый момент, когда Apache узнал, что `somepath` это директория, он отправил браузеру ответ 301 (Moved Permanently) с предложением посетить адрес `http://site.com/somepath/`. Браузер не смог отказаться от этого предложения и отправил новый GET, изменив параллельно адресную строку на новую.

Вот собственно и всё.

PS. Такое поведение Apache зашито в один из его базовых модулей - `mod_dir`.

PPS. А что касается непосредственно вашего основного вопроса, то я пока не знаю, что тут сказать. Участия htaccess и mod_rewrite я пока тут не вижу.